# How can I have a SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint doing an update on sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I have a **SQLiteConstraintException** ***UNIQUE constraint*** doing an update in sqlite ?

I'm trying to put my guids to lower case

```
db.execSQL("update user SET id = LOWER(id)");
```

> Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE
>   constraint failed: user.id (code 1555)

Comment: For a question like this, you should add the schema of the table in question (as CL noted, the collation may affect things).  Also, either confirm there are no triggers on the table (or provide them if there are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible reason for this is that there are at least two rows with a similar `id` value, and both would be the same in lowercase (e.g., `Johnduff` and `JohnDuff` would both end up as `johnduff`).

You have to find out yourself how to resolve it; if they're duplicates, delete one, otherwise, give one a new ID.

Comment: Txs CL, that should be the reason and the good answer... Do you think a try catch error is enough for avoiding duplicates ?

Comment: Constraint are designed to protect against programming errors; it's not easy to determine if an exception was caused by a constraint violation. If your program expects duplicates, it should explicitly check for them, and then do whatever needs to be done.

Answer (score -1):

Check your table CREATE command id must be defined as UNIQUE which is causing the problem.

Normally id once assigned is not allowed to change. Either remove the UNIQUE from create table or change the logic to make id lower when u first assign values

Comment: Txs Vicky for your response. But as it is guids, they must be unique and I already have upper ids in db. I'm now inserting lower ids but the question is how can I modify the existing upper ids to lower... The strange thing is that it had worked for others tables...

Comment: compare the create table command for different tables . then u will find the culprit. you cant update a unique column like after inserting remember that

Answer (score -1):

As you have defined id as UNIQUE and **UNIQUE constraint is case-insenstive**.
That's why you are getting **SQLiteConstraintException UNIQUE constraint**.
You must  change your logic you're not allowed change cases while having UNIQUE CONSTRAINT.

Comment: Whether UNIQUE constraints are case sensitive depends on the collation of the column.

Comment: @CL. yaa it depends on the collation.But if there is no collation at the time of creation of table then it will throw this exception

Comment: All columns have a collation, even if it's the default one.